# Running Windows 7/10 on MacBook via Bootcamp - Limitations

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, mac, boot-camp

I am thinking of buying a MacBook, MacBook Pro, or MacBook Air, to replace my current (and only) Laptop, which is a PC running windows.

I would like to do this “switch” because I would love to have the possibility of developing tvOS/iOS apps in a more native and better supported environment.

However, I am also a Poweruser on my Windows PC, and the key factors for me in this usage of my Windows PC are

A) I write code on it in most well-known Programming and Scripting Languages, and use several coding/development  environments (IDEs as well as simple text editors). This code is meant to be run on this Windows PC as well as on other Windows PCs.

B ) I am also a Poweruser of Excel on my Windows PC, which includes using Add-ins, writing and using macros, and using most of the other “plug-in” options that are offered for Excel on Windows.

If I buy said MacBook/MacBook Pro/MacBook Air and boot into my Windows 10 Version using bootcamp, are there any limitations to doing A and B in this “new environment”, potentially due to different Hardware Architectures of MacBooks and PCs designed for Windows/other OSs?

Are there any other limitations I need to consider when using Windows 7 / 10 on a MacBook via Bootcamp?

Comment: Never used it, but there a couple of limitations listed on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_(software)#Limitations

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but those limitations did not seem very relevant to doing A and B;) If I need additional storage I’ll get an external drive, and I didn’t ask about Linux

Comment: None whatsoever, just get one with good CPU specs and plenty of RAM and storage space. From A & B, you don't have to worry about GPU. My recommendation is to get the pro or macbook with min. 8G RAM, 500G storage, air has limited cpu, ram and storage.